# What does this scene represent?

Tags: arcane

In the seventh episode of *Arcane*, we see a fight between

> Ekko and Jinx

Since the fight is primarily conducted in a more cartoonish style, certain elements are hard to make sense of. We see a young, stylized version of Ekko moving toward Jinx (looking like Powder) while she fires paintballs at him, until one makes contact with his chest plate. Then everything reverses and moves backwards, and we see the full, CGI fight. Ekko does not appear to have taken the shot, and he dodges his way toward Jinx and knocks her down.

Does this sequence represent what actually happened in the fight scene? Is it Ekko predicting the results of the fight with his intellect? (If so, his predictions of where she would fire were extraordinarily precise). Or does he actually have some sort of temporal power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I adequately back this up with source material as I don't think this is explained within the remainder of the show...BUT

Powder(Jinx) and Ekko are previously shown to be friends when they were much younger, and it isn't much of a stretch to assume that they played together. We also know from episode 3(?) that Powder had a paintball gun when she was younger. So the way I interpret this scene is that Ekko was remembering when he played with Powder when they were younger, and that the challenge was for him to reach her with his fake sword before his timer ran out and/or he got hit with a paintball. In the flashback he fails and gets hit.
In the present, because of this learned experience, he can anticipate Jinx and therefore dodge her attacks and close to melee range.

As an aside, in the Lore, Ekko does have power over time with his Z-Drive (which allows him to rewind time), although we don't see this in season 1. I guess this is a bit of an easter egg scene for fans.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/leeloo104/status/1464409441936105474) by a writer of the show,
the scene was portraying Ekko's mental thought processes, not a particular temporal power:

> He was imagining the moves in his head and remembering his past “fights” with Powder as they [sic] way he was able to anticipate what she would do and beat her.

This is also close to what was speculated in the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/256465/51379)
.

That said, while this answer is undoubtedly canonical, it feels slightly peculiar. In his pre-battle mental simulation, Ekko's guesses as to when and where Jinx would fire were almost exactly on target, down to the number of shots, the intervals between them (adjusted for the slow motion), and their rough location relative to where he was when each shot was fired.

And indeed, to dodge four bullets, given the speed that they move at and the fact that Jinx can also adjust her shots based on where he is, he would *have* to almost know *exactly* where the bullets would be. Unless Jinx, who is notoriously chaotic, always fires in the exact same pattern that she did when she was a child, Ekko looks less like he is good at predicting how people will fight and more like he can literally see the future. The fact that the rewind effect is a dead match for his temporal powers from the games does not help dispel this impression.

Comment: I don't agree with your analysis, I think it shows him predicting how Jinx will begin the fight and how she'll react to specific moves he makes. But +1 for the source.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet - Of course that's what it shows, as indicated by the tweet. It also is the case that the accuracy of his predictions, the accuracy needed to actually dodge four bullets fired at close range, is effectively impossible for a standard human being, no matter how intelligent, and thus appears outright supernatural.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet - A bit like how when Vi, before she has her magic gauntlets and with just Vander's regular, non-magical iron gauntlets, hits an enormous minion of Silco (looking to be at least 300 pounds, so optimistically twice as heavy) hard enough to quite literally lift them off their feet and throw them backward several feet, without flying backward herself, no less. Even with her training and athleticism taken into account, if the scene is taken at face value, she quite simply has to have superhuman strength even without the gauntlets.